# Add element to Option[List[A]]

Tags: scala

I am wondering how you can append, say, variable x of type A to Option[List[A]].

```
val opt = Option[List[A]] which is initially None.
```

Now how can I add x to the List of A?

Is it:

```
opt.get ++ x
```

Does it change the opt value by using get?

Hope my question is clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it change the opt value by using get?

No, `List[A]` is immutable, in the case of using `opt.get ++ List(x)` you'd get back a new list. I wouldn't recommend using `.get` directly.

Instead, you can use `map` and `orElse` in case the list is `None` to begin with:

```
val result: Option[List[A]] = opt.map(list => x +: list).orElse(Option(List(x)))
```

An additional approach can be using `Option[A].fold`:

```
val result: Seq[Int] = opt.fold(List(x))(list => x +: list)
```

If you want to prepend the element *and* extract the list, use `getOrElse`:

```
val result: Seq[Int] = opt.map(list => x +: list).getOrElse(List(10))
```

Comment: what if i want to mutate opt? is that not possible?

Comment: @Hanming You cant mutate an immutable object.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this by doing

```
val result = Option(opt.get ++ x )
```